Draw a diagonal line in PowerPoint using Office.Js API
I hope you are well. I am facing a strange issue in Office.JS API for PowerPoint. My purpose is simple, I want to draw a diagonal line (front up), but I cannot. In the below pic, you can see it's top-up line, and in the Shape documentation, I can't find anything either.
I am not able to draw this line using the Office.JS API in the PowerPoint

I fiddled with the code below but still had no success. Any help is really appreciated.
  // This function gets the collection of shapes on the first slide,
  // and adds a line to the collection, while specifying its
  // start and end points. Then it names the shape.
  await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes: PowerPoint.ShapeCollection = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).shapes;

    // For a line, left and top are the coordinates of the start point,
    // while height and width are the coordinates of the end point.
    const line: PowerPoint.Shape = shapes.addLine(PowerPoint.ConnectorType.straight, {
      left: 400,
      top: 200,
      height: 20,
      width: 150
    });
    line.name = "StraightLine";

    await context.sync();
  });
}```





You need to say more than "I cannot" and "no success". What exactly goes wrong when you run the code?

Apologies.. there is no sucess in that..

The code you provided has a logical error in how it specifies the coordinates for the line. In PowerPoint, when adding a line, the left and top properties specify the starting point, but the width and height properties do not directly specify the end point. Instead, they specify the horizontal and vertical distances from the starting point to the ending point.
try to simply switch the last two lines
// For a line, left and top are the coordinates of the start point,
// while width and height are the horizontal and vertical distances
// from the start point to the end point.
const line = shapes.addLine(PowerPoint.ConnectorType.straight, {
    left: 400,
    top: 200,
    width: 150,  // Horizontal distance to the end point
    height: 20  // Vertical distance to the end point
});

